# SQL: Is there a way to use a new/user defined variable within the same SELECT statement?

Tags: proc-sql

I am curious if it is possible to use/reference a newly user created variable within the same SELECT statement. Below is some sample code of something I would try to do (calculate AGE and make an indicator variable for patients who are age >= 60) all within the same SELECT statement

```
create table AGE_60_UP as
     select ID
            , DATE_OF_BIRTH
            , INDEX_DATE
            , (year(INDEX_DATE) - year(DATE_OF_BIRTH)) as AGE
            , case when AGE >= 60 then 1 else 0 
            end as AGE_60_UP_INDICATOR;
     from MY_TABLE; 
quit;
```

The error message I get is:
"ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: AGE"

Thanks in advance for any help or tips!

Comment: You have tagged the question MySQL, but the code is SAS.  I'm confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a computed column to compute another computed column in the same scope. However, you can use a subquery to compute the first column, and then use it in the external query for the second computed column.

For example, you can do:

```
create table AGE_60_UP as
select *,
  case when AGE >= 60 then 1 else 0 end as AGE_60_UP_INDICATOR
from (
  select
    ID, DATE_OF_BIRTH, INDEX_DATE,
    year(INDEX_DATE) - year(DATE_OF_BIRTH) as age
  from my_table
) x
```

Comment: I see - this makes sense. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @The Impaler - I didn't realize it was possible to mix a [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) expression (like `CREATE TABLE`) with [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) expressions (like `SELECT *`) in the same SQL statement.  Q: Is that true across all major RDBMSs?  Per [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createtableas.html), it appears `CREATE TABLE AS` is indeed "standard".

Comment: @FoggyDay Yes, that is common in about all engines, though the syntax changes a bit. One extreme case is SQL Server, where you can make "composite" DDL+DML. Looks a bit crazy to me and I haven't used it but apparently you can run a bunch of statements in one go,